# how to run c++ proram with int main(int argc, char *argv[])

Tags: c++, ubuntu, argv, argc

readme.txt file:

> To use the program you should compile the file "main.cpp" and subsequently run the executable passing as the first argument the port number to 
>   which the application will listen for incoming data points (the incomplete data set that is used to approximate the original signal), (argv[1]=port number).

Incoming packets should adhere to the following format:

```
0|numSensors(int32_t)|numMeasures(int32_t)|ToM(int32_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
....
2|
```

"numMeasures" is the number of measures for taken for each sensor (you must provide at least 3 measures per 
sensor as otherwise you cannot build the training set).

"ToM" indicates the type of measurement, specifically:

```
0 for TEMPERATURE
1 for HUMIDITY
2 for LUMINOSITY1
```

> "sensorID": is the unique ID for the sensor that is sending the data
>
> "value": is the sensor reading
>
> "timestamp": you guess ...

This is the format of the packets returned by the  signal reconstruction algorithm:

```
4|next_p_tx(float)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
3|sensorId(int16_t)|value(float)|timestamp(int64_t)|
....
2|
```

"next_p_tx": is the transmission probability for the sensors, for the next data gathering round, see our publications for further info on the approach.

my question:
how to run this program on Ubuntu ? (via commandline or any IDE)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    initMeasures = (sensorMeasures*) malloc(sizeof(sensorMeasures));
    fprintf(stdout, "Starting...\n");

    int serversock, clientsock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: echoserver <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create the TCP socket */
    if ((serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        Die("Failed to create socket");
    }

    /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server)); /* Clear struct */
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; /* Internet/IP */
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Incoming addr */
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1])); /* server port */
    /* Bind the server socket */
    if (bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        Die("Failed to bind the server socket");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Bind successful...\n");
    }
    /* Listen on the server socket */
    if (listen(serversock, MAXPENDING) < 0) {
        Die("Failed to listen on server socket");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Listen successful...\n");
    }
    /*
     * Initialization of  "last"
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        last[i].Phi_prec = new Matrix(1, 1);
        (*last[i].Phi_prec)(1, 1) = 0;
        last[i].x_prec = new ColumnVector(1);
        (*last[i].x_prec)(1) = 0;
        last[i].y_prec = new ColumnVector(1);
        (*last[i].y_prec)(1) = 0;
        last[i].p_tx = 1.0;
        last[i].depth = 0;
    }
    /* Run until cancelled */
    while (1) {
        unsigned int clientlen = sizeof(client);
        printf("Wait for client connection...\n");
        if ((clientsock = accept(serversock, (struct sockaddr *) &client,
                &clientlen)) < 0) {
            Die("Failed to accept client connection");
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Client connected: %s:%d\n",
                inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));

        now = time(NULL);
        receiveData(clientsock); // receive socket data
        reconstruct(); // reconstruct received data
        sendResults(clientsock); // return reconstructed data to web application
        printf("All operations successfully completed...\n");
    }
    free(initMeasures);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: It says it right there in the readme. What part of "compile and run this program" do you not understand?

Comment: Normally, stackoverflow users are not interested in all your program --only on the specific problem. For future posts, try to be more compact and simplify everything.

Answer (score 2):

> To use the program you should compile the file "main.cpp"

That's `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o echoserver main.cpp`

> and subsequently run the executable passing as the first argument the port number

That's `./echoserver 12345` replacing the number with whichever port you want to listen to.

Comment: Pretty please enable compiler warnings? Otherwise we'll have to swat off the next fifty questions about trivial stuff that the compiler would have happily spelled out.

Comment: @KerrekSB: OK. Now we'll get questions about what the warnings mean instead.

Comment: That's fine, I'd be a hundred times happier with people asking about configuring warnings :-) Thanks!